# Typescript knows import -> require but doesn't know require -> import?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, es6-modules

I have a simple file which is using es6 module loader :

**1.ts**

```
import {foo} from "./2"
foo('hello');
```

**2.ts**

```
function foo (a){console.log(a);};
export {foo}
```

When tsconfig is set to :

```
"module": "commonjs",
```

We can see that it converts `import` to `require` :

**(output)1.js**

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var _2_1 = require("./2");
_2_1.foo('hello');
```

That's fine. But if I now  use module loading via `require` :

**1.ts**

```
var a = require("./2")
a('hello');
```

**2.ts**

```
function foo (a){console.log(a);};
module.exports.foo= foo
```

And set `"module": "es6",` : then the output is :

**(output)1.js**

```
var a = require("./2");  // why it didnt compile it to `import` ??
a('hello');
```

**Question:**

What is the reason that TS can't compile  `require` to `import` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript normalised their syntax on the ECMAScript version of the import syntax. All of your TypeScript code should use this style:

```
import { ZipCodeValidator } from "./ZipCodeValidator";
```

The compiler will happily convert this into the AMD, CommonJS, or System style of imports - but it doesn't unidirectionally map from each of these to each other one of these.

So the short version is, write ECMAScript imports and use the compiler flag to have them converted into whatever you like.

As an aside, when actually intending to use the ECMAScript module loader, adding `.js` works within the import statement - i.e. TypeScript understands what you mean.

Comment: Thanks. can you please explain the _reason_ why it can't ? is ther any plan to do so ?

Comment: Because there is only a _target_ module kind flag, not a _source_ module kind flag. The syntax for TypeScript imports is the ECMAScript syntax, so while it will let you write whatever JavaScript code you like, it won't seek out everything that could be a module import and substitute it back to ECMAScript style.

Comment: Make sense. Thank you.